# Index not used on partitioned table

Tags: mysql, index, partitioning, explain

We have a table similar to this one

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE my_requests\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: my_requests
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `my_requests` (
  `rq_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `t_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `u_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rq_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `rq_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `rq_creationdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `rq_modifydate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `rq_ttotal` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `index_rqcd` (`t_id`,`rq_date`),
  KEY `idx_rq_u` (`u_id`),
  KEY `idx_rq_id` (`rq_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY LIST (to_days(rq_date))
SUBPARTITION BY HASH (t_id)
SUBPARTITIONS 10
(PARTITION p736417 VALUES IN (736417) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736419 VALUES IN (736419) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736430 VALUES IN (736430) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736439 VALUES IN (736439) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736443 VALUES IN (736443) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736444 VALUES IN (736444) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736445 VALUES IN (736445) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736446 VALUES IN (736446) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736447 VALUES IN (736447) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736448 VALUES IN (736448) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736449 VALUES IN (736449) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736450 VALUES IN (736450) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736451 VALUES IN (736451) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736452 VALUES IN (736452) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736453 VALUES IN (736453) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736454 VALUES IN (736454) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736455 VALUES IN (736455) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736456 VALUES IN (736456) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736457 VALUES IN (736457) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736458 VALUES IN (736458) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736459 VALUES IN (736459) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736460 VALUES IN (736460) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736461 VALUES IN (736461) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736462 VALUES IN (736462) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736463 VALUES IN (736463) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736464 VALUES IN (736464) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736465 VALUES IN (736465) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736466 VALUES IN (736466) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736467 VALUES IN (736467) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736468 VALUES IN (736468) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p736469 VALUES IN (736469) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

with **partitions by day**, the table is huge and has **hundreds of millions of registers**, and I'm trying to select the **data from the last day** and avoid a full scan and access only the last partitions.

But when I do a explain the index is not used.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_requests USE INDEX(index_rqcd)
     WHERE t_id <> -1 AND rq_date = DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | my_requests | ALL  | index_rqcd    | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4020468 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

**Edit:**
The `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS` shows that the query only affect part of the partitions, but I still don't understand why the index is not used.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * FROM my_requests
         WHERE t_id <> -1 AND rq_date = DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: my_requests
   partitions: p736467_p736467sp0,p736467_p736467sp1,p736467_p736467sp2,p736467_p736467sp3,p736467_p736467sp4,p736467_p736467sp5,p736467_p736467sp6,p736467_p736467sp7,p736467_p736467sp8,p736467_p736467sp9
         type: ALL
possible_keys: index_rqcd
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 4064737
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

Can you help me to understand why this index is not used for that query?

Comment: Do an `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS` on that query, that should show that it is doing partition pruning.

Comment: Shouldn't `rq_date` be first in some index for your query to be able to use it for ref access? And some [info](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#partitioning) about usefulness of partitioning.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70ad9/2

Comment: @jkavalik well, there is index_rqcd that is an index whit both the conditions used in the where part of the query. I'd expect to be used in this case.

Comment: @pconcepcion the order of columns in the index definition matters

Comment: @jkavalik I know, that's why I'm usign both `t_id` and `rq_date` in the `WHERE` clause of the query, if I was just using `rq_date` I'd understand that the index is not used because it's the second column of the index, but if I'm using both I don't get why it's not used.

Comment: @pconcepcion because you check ` t_id <> -1` - that's a *range* scan and it "disables" any other index access for columns defined after that. You use `=` for `rq_date` which is a *ref* access and does not have this effect. That's why having it **first** in the index is important as I wrote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

First, as jkavalik says in the comments on the OP, the order of columns in an index matters.  Basically, in your case for `index_rqcd` to be used for filtering on `rq_date`, `t_id` has to be used before it can "see" and filter on `rq_date`.  Since usually only one range scan on an index can be done for a query and it has to be the last part of the index used, the optimizer correctly skips using this index because it would probably have to use the entire index which cause a full scan on the index and then a full scan on the table, or in this case partition.  If the table and had an index starting with `rq_date`, that index would likely be used.

Second, something you should be aware of when using partitions is that MySQL doesn't have global indexes for partitioned tables.  What this means is that each partition has its own indexes and therefore can only be used inside that partition.  Since the optimizer knows that the query only needs to use partition `p736467` based on the query and table definition (an optimization known as partition pruning), only that partition, and in your case the associated sub-partitions, are considered when running the query.  So now that the optimizer is only using partition `p736467`, it can consider using `index_rqcd`, but since it is still affected by the first problem and its use would lead to a full scan on the index, it chooses to do a full scan on the data.  Even though the `EXPLAIN` shows `ALL` for the type, it is only scanning the data in the `p736467` partition, not the entire table, because of the partition pruning.  Even if you add an index starting with `rq_date`, it will not be used  if you want to get all of the rows for the day the partition is for.  However, the query you give will only return rows for exactly 1 day ago down to the second, not the whole day as you say when describing what you want to do.  If you really do want to get rows for a specific time and not the whole day, and index starting with `rq_date` will be useful.

Probably the most important thing here is that, as mentioned by the link jkavalik posted, you shouldn't use partitions unless you have a good reason to.  Time ranges can be a valid use for partitions, but usually only when used with a sliding window of chronological data, e.g. 7 days of log messages that are pruned daily.  Generally unless you can use partition pruning in (almost) every query, they will hurt performance since every partition will likely need to be accessed.  If you are always querying this table for rows on a specific date and then filtering on a range on some other indexed column, partitions might be useful.  More likely, partitions are not the right way to go.  Unless you have a *very* good reason to use the sub-partitions, they are almost certainly just adding overhead to every query.

My suggestion, assuming that most of your queries are based on a range of `rq_date`, is to not use partitions and add an index starting with `rq_date`.

Also, when using InnoDB, you should always define a primary key.  I don't know about the data you're storing, but it looks like `rq_id` might be unique and a good candidate.

Comment: In fact we use a **sliding window of chronological data** and we drop the oldest partition everyday and create a new one for the current day.
On the other hand most of the queries are done using the `rq_id` (wich is as you said is a good candiate for PK) or `t_id` or `u_id` and quering by `rq_date` is not our main use case.
We use partitions mainly because of the size of the table and in order use the  sliding window and be able to delete the old data just droping the last partition.

Comment: If a `SELECT` hits all partitions, it is less efficient than a non-partitioned table.  However, the benefits of partitioning for a "sliding window" more than makes up for it.  (My opinion.)

Answer (score 1):

3 problems with that partitioning:

- `BY HASH` is useless.
- `SUBPARTITIONing` is useless.
- Hundreds of partitions is inefficient.

Stick with only `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(rq_date))`.  The big benefit is in the 'sliding window'.

More comments in [*my partitioning blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

What percentage of rows have `t_id <> -1`?  If more than about 20%, it won't use an index unless your `PRIMARY KEY` *starts with* `t_id`.  And, can you change `t_id <> -1` into `t_id > -1`?  That might help the optimizer do a "range" test; `<>` is harder to optimize.

InnoDB really wants you to have an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.  Are any of your columns (or combination of columns) already "unique"?  If so, it/they should be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  However, you would need to tack `rq_date` on the end.  There was mention of `rq_id`, so you might end up with

```
PRIMARY KEY(t_id, rq_id_, rq_date)
```

That's getting a bit long, so maybe it is not best.  We need to better understand your columns.